# How to override Material UI theme with Typescript from a separate file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to override Material UI theme like the below:

```
// theme.ts

const theme: Theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        display: 'inline-block',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        textAlign: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderRadius: 0,
        minWidth: 120
      },
      containedPrimary: {
        boxShadow: 'none'
      },
      containedSecondary: {
        boxShadow: 'none',
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: 'grey'
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but putting all the overrides in one file will make it very long. So I tried to put each override in a separate file, like the below.

```
// theme.ts

const theme: Theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: MuiButtonOverrides
  }
}
```

And my MuiButtonOverrides.ts looks like:

```
// MuiButtonOverrides.ts

export default {
  root: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textDecoration: 'none',
    textAlign: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    borderRadius: 0,
    minWidth: 120
  },
  containedPrimary: {
    boxShadow: 'none'
  },
  containedSecondary: {
    boxShadow: 'none',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'grey'
    }
  }
};
```

But this doesn't work and Typescript complains that:

```
Type '{ root: { display: string; fontWeight: string; textDecoration: string; textAlign: string; verticalAlign: string; borderRadius: number; minWidth: number; }; containedPrimary: { boxShadow: string; }; containedSecondary: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<ButtonClassKey, CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}> | PropsFunc<{}, CreateCSSProperties<{}>>>>'.
  Types of property 'root' are incompatible.
    Type '{ display: string; fontWeight: string; textDecoration: string; textAlign: string; verticalAlign: string; borderRadius: number; minWidth: number; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}> | PropsFunc<{}, CreateCSSProperties<{}>> | undefined'.
      Type '{ display: string; fontWeight: string; textDecoration: string; textAlign: string; verticalAlign: string; borderRadius: number; minWidth: number; }' is not assignable to type 'CreateCSSProperties<{}>'.
```

Seems that the `root` is the problem, because when I removed it, then the error is gone. I'm not sure what is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem.

The problem is in the `fontWeight` and `textAlign`. In this case, `fontWeight` only accepts number, so I should've use `700` instead of `bold`.

For `textAlign`, it works when I put `textAlign: "center" as const`.